# Hiding a <td> depending on the Condition

Tags: javascript

I have a table structure as given below:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td id="td1"> </td>
  <td id="td2"> </td>
  <td id="td3"> </td>
  <td id="td4"> </td> 
 </tr>
</table>
```

I am checking some condition like:

```
if(a==2 || check == true)
```

I want to hide the "td3" if any one condition satisfies.

My code is in C#.

I have already tried

```
document.getelementbyId("td3").style("display"= "none"),
document.getelementbyId("td3").display.hide();
td3.Attributes.add("style", "display:none")
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `C#`, `asp.net` or `vb.net`?

Comment: *Need solution as soon as possible* - Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: `My code is in C#.` yet all I see is HTML and JavaScript. What code is in c#?

Comment: before adding immature comment, develop a holistic thinking capability. thanx for comment though!

Answer (score 5):

Your three JavaScript examples aren't valid JavaScript. I recommend reading the JavaScript docs a bit more in depth!

You can use the code below to hide the `td`.

```js
document.getElementById("td3").style.display = "none";
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="td1">TD1</td>
        <td id="td2">TD2</td>
        <td id="td3">TD3</td>
        <td id="td4">TD4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#td3').hide()
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="td1">TD1</td>
        <td id="td2">TD2</td>
        <td id="td3">TD3</td>
        <td id="td4">TD4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```